# Past Buddha's : Sources

Tags: sutras, buddhas, paramitas

I came  along with this (http://www.aathaapi.net/dwncounter.php?number=29)  detailed description of the Buddhas (during vag and mano pradani era of Gautama Bodhisattva) before the 28 Buddhas. 512000 in number to be exact. I have also heard about this fact in some texts as well.

Is this stated in the pali canon? What are the sutras?

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the (dubious) [Digha Nikaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digha_Nikaya), particularly the [Mahāpadāna Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/en/dn14).

> *It is now ninety-one aeons ago, brethren, since Vipassī, the Exalted One, Arahant, Buddha Supreme, arose in the world. It is now thirty-one
>   aeons ago, brethren, since Sikhi, the Exalted One, Arahant, Buddha
>   Supreme, arose in the world. It was in that same thirty-first aeon,
>   brethren, that Vessabhu, the Exalted One, Arahant, Buddha Supreme,
>   arose in the world. It was in this present auspicious aeon, brethren,
>   that Kakusandha, the Exalted One, Arahant, Buddha Supreme, arose in
>   the world. It was in this auspicious aeon, brethren, that Koṇāgamana,
>   the Exalted One, Arahant, Buddha Supreme, arose in the world. It was
>   in this auspicious aeon, brethren, that Kassapa, the Exalted One,
>   Arahant, Buddha Supreme, arose in the world. It is in this auspicious
>   aeon, brethren, that now I, an Arahant, Buddha Supreme, have arisen in
>   the world.*

[MN 50](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/2Majjhima-Nikaya/Majjhima1/050-maratajjhaniya-sutta-e1.html) also contains a story.

> *Venerable Mahāmoggallāna saw the Evil One stuck in the throat and said, I see you there too. You are stuck in the throat. In the past
>   there was an Evil One named Dūsi. To me there was a sister named Kāli.
>   You were her son. Then you were my nephew. It was at the time of the
>   perfect rightfully enlightened Blessed One Kakusanda's time. To the
>   perfect rightfully Enlightened One, Kakusanada, there were two chief
>   disciples named Vidura and Sañjīva*

(Disclaimer: Based on human & social evolution, I personally doubt there were any past Buddhas. For example, the Mahāpadāna Sutta appears state the very first Buddha had 6,800,000 or 68 lacs arahant disciples; the older the Buddha, the more arahant disciples they had, which seems to contradict historical evidence of human population. The above genre of suttas that number a handful among 1,000s of suttas, which also contradict [SN 22.79](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn22.79) in talking about literal 'personal' past lives, I would speculate were later writings rather than words of the Buddha.)

Comment: I don't think you can ever compare with the human and social evolution with the Buddha eons. Because the current social and human evolution is based on the tangible evidences we have and it is still changing. Also a Maha kappa(aeon that is mentioned above) is a world cycle that contains the creation and destruction of the universe. For every aeon this happens. Also 91 aeons ago means 91 cycles like i mentioned above(91 big bangs in other terms) ago. So we actually don't have sufficient evidence to even.

Comment: And in Mahapadana sutra it is talking about the 1st Buddha of the past 7 buddhas. That doesn't mean that there weren't before. Also there is no possible way of having tangible evidences of the Vipassi buddha cause it was 91 world cycles ago. 91 big bangs ago. So there is no possible way of reaching that history unless a person achieve a higher state of mind and see for himself